# selenium protractor webdriver-manager update issue in ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm facing the error below when I run webdriver-manager update command.

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cmds/start.js:60
        if (path.isAbsolute(options[Opt.OUT_DIR].getString())) {
                 ^ TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isAbsolute'
    at Program.start [as runMethod] (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cmds/start.js:60:18)
    at Program.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/programs.js:60:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/webdriver.js:25:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager:3:1)
```

Any ideas how to deal with that?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `npm install -g protractor` to get the newest protractor.

Comment: Okay . I requested them